# failed to unmarshal interface java.util.List after changing JNDI URL protocol vom t3 to iiop

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic

We are running an application on **4 WLS-Nodes on different UNIX machines**.

- OS: Sun 5.10.
- WLS: WebLogic Server 12.2.1.3.0
- Java: jdk1.8.0_144

Most of the communication between the nodes is done via `EJB`.
For a long time we have set up the `JNDI URL` with the T3 protocol: 
`JNDI_URL=t3://xxxsixb10001:8001,xxxixb10002:8001`

Now we're using:

`JNDI_URL=iiop://xxxsixb10001:8001,xxxixb10002:8001`

As we had heavy load balancing problems when shutting down single nodes, we were informed by Oracle to switch the protocol from T3 to **IIOP**.

After configuration of all 4 nodes, we receive an `javax.ejb.EJBException` when invoking EJB requests.

The main error seems to be:

```
13.06.2018 15:28:17.368 [Admin Request 18] Thd#64 admin.login [APPLICATION_ERROR] oginUtils.getAllClients Wrapped Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: failed to unmarshal interface java.util.List; nested exception is:    
             java.rmi.UnmarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 0 No; nested exception is:
             org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: CORBA MARSHAL 0 No; nested exception is:
             org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: CORBA MARSHAL 0 No; nested exception is:
             org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: CORBA MARSHAL 0 No; nested exception is:
             org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: CORBA MARSHAL 0 No; nested exception is:
             org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: CORBA MARSHAL 0 No; nested exception is:
             org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Failed to invoke readObject() on java.util.HashSet vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No
    exception.SystemException: Wrapped Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: failed to unmarshal interface java.util.List; nested exception is:
             java.rmi.UnmarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 0 No; nested exception is:
             org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: CORBA MARSHAL 0 No; nested exception is:
             org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: CORBA MARSHAL 0 No; nested exception is:
             org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: CORBA MARSHAL 0 No; nested exception is:
             org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: CORBA MARSHAL 0 No; nested exception is:
             org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: CORBA MARSHAL 0 No; nested exception is:
             org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Failed to invoke readObject() on java.util.HashSet vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 0 completed: No
```

Comment: You need to ensure that all your remote method arguments are `java.io.Serializable`.

Comment: The code works with protocol T3. Why to change working code for protocol IIOP?

Comment: as Oracle marks IIOP as deprecated, switching the protocol is not a question anymore